# can i block others from merging any cell without protecting them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The title says everything, I just need another user of my sheet to fill cell without giving them the right of merging any cell.
I have tried I'm going to use the filled cell in one other sheet using index formula and if they merge cell I don't get the right result.

```
<== C3&" "&D3&" "&E3
```

[image: this is an example of the problem]

Comment: What you can do with Apps Script, is to check on every cell edit, either the edited cell is merged and if this is the case - unmerge it and display a message box, telling the user that merging is not allowed. Would that be a good solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

Change F6 to:

```
=C6&" "&D5&" "&E5
```

The merged cell references the first merged row number.

Comment: Something can probably be done with Google apps script. Without a sample spreadsheet it is hard to determine what you need to do,

Comment: i just need to consider the 2 merged cells with the same value in the up cell